# Is there a CSS/JavaScript framework available that helps mimic the iOS home screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, homescreen

Does an iOS-home-screen-like framework exist in CSS/JavaScript? I'd like to make a kiosk with a similar feel to the Android/iOS home screen. This would be a desktop webpage with "apps" in a grid layout.

Comment: Is this for mobile or desktop? Can you also please elaborate on 'home screen'? e.g. the grid of icons when you turn the device on or the initial 'home screen' when you open an app or settings?

Comment: I'm making a kiosk for a touchscreen terminal (also see edit)

Comment: like this? http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/10/ios-homescreen-coffeescript/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and edit I would use a grided CSS framework like [960](http://www.960.gs) for example, doing a Google search for "grid css" will give a number of options available. I would then store the information in a database and call it via AJAX.

[jQuery Mobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com) may also give you some functionality for a touch screen terminal that could help.

I hope this helps